# Where is program searching for a file "/.txr/tix.conf"

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I am running a program on linux fedora in debug mode. And I get the error message

```
Startup Warning : Failed to open up profile at "/.txr/tix.conf"
```

I wanted to know what the location of of the tix file should be . I tried putting it in

```
Debug/txr/tix.conf
```

However that does not work as the program complains about the same thing. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It looks like it's trying to access the path "`/.txr/tix.conf`" to me.  Use `strace` to find out what it's "really" doing.

Comment: Configuration files like this usually go into a user's home directory. It looks like the program is not correctly substituting the user's home directory before appending "/.txr/tix.conf".